# Bold part of string in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I tried to use this method, but it changes only the first time that `textToMark` is shown in the `richTextBox` and I want it to change every time `textToMark` is contained:

```
public static void ChangeTextcolor(string textToMark, Color color, RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;

        string text = richTextBox.Text;
        startIndex = text.IndexOf(textToMark);

        System.Drawing.Font newFont = new Font("Verdana", 10f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 178, false);

        try
        {
            foreach (string line in richTextBox.Lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(textToMark))
                {
                    richTextBox.Select(startIndex, textToMark.Length);
                    richTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
                    richTextBox.SelectionFont = newFont;
                }
            }
        }
        catch{ }
    }
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Use a RichTextBox. The simpler TextBox has no way to individually format single words

Comment: Use a RichTextBox instead. And you didn't search very hard.

Answer (score -1):

You can use RichTextBox Control. [**Formatting Characters in Bold in a RichTextBox Control (Visual C#)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```

Comment: Thank you all. I will try it.

Comment: @RonF did it help ?

Comment: It helped but still I dont know how to make specific words be bold and the other regular

Comment: @RonF @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}"; write the text like this the bold part in \b bold \b

Comment: Hi I changed my question, Can you help me?